# My code doesn't store anything in mySql wb

Tags: java, spring

I made a Spring Boot program that consumes API from a site (https://www.thecocktaildb.com) and returns all drinks that contain the name i insert. It works and returns the value I enter at the endpoint I specified.

```
package com.example.esercizio.Controller;


import com.example.esercizio.Model.Drink;
import com.example.esercizio.Model.DrinkList;
import com.example.esercizio.Repository.DrinkRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DrinkController {
    @Autowired
    private DrinkRepository drinkRepository;

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1";

    public RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @GetMapping("/cocktails/{name}")
    public DrinkList drinksByName (@PathVariable String name){
        DrinkList drinks = restTemplate.getForObject(BASE_URL + "/search.php?s=" + name, DrinkList.class);
        if(drinks != null){
            return drinks;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I want to store those returning values into a database. So i modified the code this way below:

```
package com.example.esercizio.Controller;

import com.example.esercizio.Model.Drink;
import com.example.esercizio.Model.DrinkList;
import com.example.esercizio.Repository.DrinkRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DrinkController {
    @Autowired
    private DrinkRepository drinkRepository;

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1";

    public RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @GetMapping("/cocktails/{name}")
    public DrinkList drinksByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        DrinkList drinks = restTemplate.getForObject(BASE_URL + "/search.php?s=" + name, DrinkList.class);
        if (drinks != null) {
            for (Drink drink : drinks.getDrinks()) {
                if (!drinkRepository.existsById(drink.getIdDrink())) {
                    drinkRepository.save(drink);
                }
            }
            return drinks;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that now it doesn't work anymore, it gives me back a white label page at the endpoint (error 500). Also it does create an empty table in mySql. I'll also put below the code for the model and the interface implemented with jpa.

```
package com.example.esercizio.Model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name="drink")
public class Drink {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String idDrink;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String strDrink;
    @Column(name="glass")
    private String strGlass;
    @Column(name="instructions")
    private String strInstructions;
    private String strDrinkThumb;
    @Column(name="ingr1")
    private String strIngredient1;
    @Column(name="ingr2")
    private String strIngredient2;
    @Column(name="ingr3")
    private String strIngredient3;


    public Drink(){

    }

// I didn't put all the getters and setters here, it would be too long, but in the real code are all here. //
```

```
package com.example.esercizio.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DrinkRepository extends JpaRepository<Drink, String> {
}
```

And then the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cocktails
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

I feel like there is something missing, but I tried a lot of stuff, like putting @transactional or separating the service, but it still doesn't seem to work. Thank you for the patience and help.

Comment: it would help if you update your question with the actual 500 error, i.e., the exception you are getting

Comment: an example of the response you are getting from your search on www.thecocktaildb.com will also help. I've done a request to test it and from what I see your entity matches with the response, but drop and example anyway pls